# Что значит i в цикле for?

Tags: python, переменные

Есть пример:

```
for i in 'hello world':
    print(i * 2, end='')

# hheelllloo  wwoorrlldd
```

Что означает `i` в принципе?

В другом вопросе ответили, что это переменные. Но как я понял, здесь должны быть переменными `hello` и `world`. Или в питоне переменные являются буквами этих слов?

Comment: или все-таки слова hello и world это и есть переменные, а умножение (i * 2) просто умножает каждую букву в этих переменных?

Comment: А вы не Гууглить, а просто открыть учебник по Python не пытались?  Ну, немножко дальне чем "начало", хотя-бы до раздела "циклы"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл `for` при обработке строки '`hello world`' проходит по каждой букве в этой строке. 
На каждой итерации цикла в переменную **`i`** попадает один символ строки.

Comment: спасибо, это объясняет то, что там происходит. Я много читал в учебниках про while и for там почему-то этого не было. То есть итератором там является все выражение в кавычках 'Hello world' как я понял? И делает с этим итератором вот такое удвоение каждой буквы?

Comment: @Arrenn Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @S.Nick да я почти получил ответ, осталось ток уточнить там итератором (i) будет являться полностью два слова 'Hello world'?

Comment: @Arrenn https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/13_iterator_generator/iterable.html

Comment: @Arrenn Чтобы принять ответ нужно нажать налочку слева от него (ответа), а не в профиле

Comment: @МаксимФисман да все ок, не так понял. Я воспринял так, что закрывать вопросы самому надо, а тут речь о том, чтобы просто выделить правильный.

Comment: @S.Nick за сайт спасибо, не до конца честно говоря понятно, что там написано, но хотя бы теперь знаю направления куда копать по этому вопросу. Примерно понимаю о чем речь, дальше попробую разобраться. Если будет какой-то вопрос и что-то не найду или не пойму насчет итерации и итератора, создам тему.